# meaning of a regular expression in a javascript statement

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to know what is the meaning of the regular expression contained within this javascript statement :

```
V.src=V.src.replace(/jsvk[^.]*/,"jsvk_off");
```

Comment: who is voting down the question, what is the problem with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern is very basic, a quick tutorial will give you the meaning:

```
/       # pattern delimiter
jsvk    # literal: jsvk
[^.]*   # all that is not a dot zero or more times
/       # pattern delimiter
```

the pattern will replace the first `"jsvk"` and all that is not a dot after the first `"jsvk"` in the string with `"jsvk_off"`

examples:

```
jsvklol.png                  =>  jsvk_off.png
jsvklol.png    jsvklol.png   =>  jsvk_off.png    jsvklol.png
jsvk jsvk jsvk.png           =>  jsvk_off.png
```

Comment: Ok @Casimir, just for avoiding confusion : what would be the replacing string if we had "jsvklol.png" ?

Comment: @mounaim: you will obtain: `jsvk_off.png`

Answer (score 1):

It means, "the string 'jsvk' followed by any number of characters other than '.'". The overall effect of the statement is to replace all occurrences of "jsvk" and everything after that up to either '.' or the end of the string with "jsvk_off". (If there is a ".", it's removed.)

So if `V.src` were "Hello jsvk oolong tea." the replacement would result in "Hello jsvk_off".

Answer (score 1):

**pattern** :    /jsvk[^.]*/

**Explanation**

```
jsvk matches the characters jsvk literally (case sensitive)

[^.]* match a single character not present in the list below

Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times,as many times as possible,
            giving back as needed [greedy]

. the literal character .
```